# Jqgrid 'setLabel' does not work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I just tried using [setLabel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to change the column name in a jqgrid. But it doesn't work. The docs says :

> **Method :** setLabel
>
> **Parameter :**
> colname,
> data,
> class,
> properties
>
> **Returns :** jqGrid object
>
> **Description :**
> Sets a new label in the header for the specified column; can also set attributes and classes . The parameters are:
> colname the name of the column (this parameter can be a number (the index of the column) beginning from 0
> data the content that can be put into the label. If empty string the content will not be changed
> class if class is string then we add a class to the label using addClass; if class is an array we set the new css properties via css
> properties sets the attribute properies of the label

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m6DQk/

**HTML**

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

**JS**  (Note the last 3 statements here)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: 'invdate',
        index: 'invdate',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        width: 100
    }, {
        name: 'amount',
        index: 'amount',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float"
    }, {
        name: 'tax',
        index: 'tax',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float"
    }, {
        name: 'total',
        index: 'total',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float"
    }, {
        name: 'note',
        index: 'note',
        width: 150,
        sortable: false
    }],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});
var mydata = [{
    id: "1",
    invdate: "2007-10-01",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
}, {
    id: "2",
    invdate: "2007-10-02",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
}, {
    id: "3",
    invdate: "2007-09-01",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
}, {
    id: "4",
    invdate: "2007-10-04",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
}, {
    id: "5",
    invdate: "2007-10-05",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
}, {
    id: "6",
    invdate: "2007-09-06",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
}, {
    id: "7",
    invdate: "2007-10-04",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
}, {
    id: "8",
    invdate: "2007-10-03",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
}, {
    id: "9",
    invdate: "2007-09-01",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
}];
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++){
        $("#list").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
    }
    
    $("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 1,"aa");
    $("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 2,"bb");
    $("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 3,"cc");
    
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 1,"aa");
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 2,"bb");
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', 3,"cc");
```

to

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', "id","aa"); //colModel name value
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', "invdate","bb");
$("#list").jqGrid('setLabel', "name","cc");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use just use column names instead of column positions as parameter of `setLabel`.

See updated code http://jsfiddle.net/m6DQk/1/.